# When do bolts get "saved"?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one

In playing through the game I'm noticing my bolt counter in the upper right hand corner is reset from time to time but when I go to purchase items from the store the bolt number is much higher. When do the bolts get "banked", and is there a way to find out what my banked bolt amount is?

Comment: To augment the question I've discovered that you can get your total bolt count by hitting L2 (maybe R2?) on the PS3 controller during gameplay. (Not sure what the equivalent is on other platforms.)

Comment: I don't think this game is available on any systems aside from the PS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bolts get saved (and your current total reset to 0) when a Scanning Minion appears, causing the totals screen to show up.